# $event.value is undefined in Polymer Dropdown Menu's Selected Item Changed event with Angular2 binding

Tags: angular, polymer

I need to retrieve the selected item in a Polymer Dropdown to set the items of another. In my code below, the value I'm getting for $event.value is undefined. How should I pass the selected value to the changed event handler?

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Country"
                     (selected-item-changed)="GetAdmin1s($event.value)">
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" [selected]="selectedCountry">
        <paper-item *ngFor="#country of countries" value="{{country.Id}}">{{country.Name}}</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what works for me. polymer seems to like using the selected property, which is the index.  The `selectedScreenRatioIndex` is a getter/setter.

by the way, this isn't pure polymer, I'm also using angular2 for the component/bindings.

```js
 <paper-dropdown-menu class="flex" label="Screen Ratio"  >
            <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" [selected]="selectedScreenRatioIndex"
                           (selected-changed)="selectedScreenRatioIndex=$event.detail.value"
                           style="font-size: large">
                <paper-item *ngFor="let myscreenratio of screenRatios">{{myscreenratio}}</paper-item>
            </paper-listbox>
 </paper-dropdown-menu>
```